# Template redirect inside of plugin not redirecting

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, redirect

I have this inside of my plugin but it's not loading it ...

```
 function templateRedirect()
 {
if(is_home()){
    echo 'hello';
}
 }
  add_action('template_redirect', 'templateRedirect');
```

Comment: Have you checked if is_home is true? does it work without the `if` statement?

Comment: Yes I checked it's true.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.   As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.